# CUDA linking errors with g++

Tags: gcc, cuda, g++

I have written a makefile that compiles multiple files and then link them together. this is the output of my file:

```
g++ -c -Wall -U DEBUG -U FILE -U HighPriority -U OnlyCUDA -U CUDA -U THREAD_NUM -U SIZE -U InputFileName -D SIZE=32 -D THREAD_NUM=4 -D CUDA \
    ../src/lib/Decomp/NT_FFT_Decomp.cpp -std=c++0x -o NT_FFT_Decomp.o
g++ -c -Wall -U DEBUG -U FILE -U HighPriority -U OnlyCUDA -U CUDA -U THREAD_NUM -U SIZE -U InputFileName -D SIZE=32 -D THREAD_NUM=4 -D CUDA \
    ../src/lib/Decomp/T_FFT_Decomp.cpp -std=c++0x -lpthread -o T_FFT_Decomp.o
g++ -c -Wall -U DEBUG -U FILE -U HighPriority -U OnlyCUDA -U CUDA -U THREAD_NUM -U SIZE -U InputFileName -D SIZE=32 -D THREAD_NUM=4 -D CUDA \
    ../src/lib/Comp/SNT_FFT_Comp.cpp -std=c++0x -o SNT_FFT_Comp.o
g++ -c -Wall -U DEBUG -U FILE -U HighPriority -U OnlyCUDA -U CUDA -U THREAD_NUM -U SIZE -U InputFileName -D SIZE=32 -D THREAD_NUM=4 -D CUDA \
    ../src/lib/Comp/ST_FFT_Comp.cpp -std=c++0x -lpthread -o ST_FFT_Comp.o
g++ -c -Wall -U DEBUG -U FILE -U HighPriority -U OnlyCUDA -U CUDA -U THREAD_NUM -U SIZE -U InputFileName -D SIZE=32 -D THREAD_NUM=4 -D CUDA \
    ../src/lib/Comp/VNT_FFT_Comp.cpp -std=c++0x -o VNT_FFT_Comp.o
g++ -c -Wall -U DEBUG -U FILE -U HighPriority -U OnlyCUDA -U CUDA -U THREAD_NUM -U SIZE -U InputFileName -D SIZE=32 -D THREAD_NUM=4 -D CUDA \
    ../src/lib/Comp/VT_FFT_Comp.cpp -std=c++0x -lpthread -o VT_FFT_Comp.o
nvcc -c -U DEBUG -U FILE -U HighPriority -U OnlyCUDA -U CUDA -U THREAD_NUM -U SIZE -U InputFileName -D SIZE=32 -D THREAD_NUM=4 -D CUDA \
    ../src/lib/Comp/CUDA_FFT_Comp.cu -o CUDA_FFT_Comp.o
ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_00001e2d_00000000-5_CUDA_FFT_Comp.ptx, line 93; warning : Double is not supported. Demoting to float
g++ -c -Wall -U DEBUG -U FILE -U HighPriority -U OnlyCUDA -U CUDA -U THREAD_NUM -U SIZE -U InputFileName -D SIZE=32 -D THREAD_NUM=4 -D CUDA \
    ../src/lib/Globals.cpp -std=c++0x -o Globals.o
g++ -c -Wall -U DEBUG -U FILE -U HighPriority -U OnlyCUDA -U CUDA -U THREAD_NUM -U SIZE -U InputFileName -D SIZE=32 -D THREAD_NUM=4 -D CUDA \
    ../src/main.cpp -std=c++0x -lpthread -o main.o
In file included from ../src/inlcude/FFT.h:12:0,
                 from ../src/main.cpp:3:
../src/inlcude/Comp/CUDA_FFT_Comp.h:14:19: fatal error: cuda.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I have the added the cuda lib and lib64 to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. and added -lcuda and -lcudart to the command.I don't get why it still generates an error.
this is my LD_LIBRARY_PATH :

```
SomePath:/media/wiso/Programs/Setups/CUDA/lib:/media/wiso/Programs/Setups/CUDA/lib64:somePath
```

this is the command that generates the error :

```
g++ $(Objects) -lcuda -lcudart -lpthread -o DevicesTest
```

In case this line is not what generated the error,These is the previous line too.
the one that creates main.o:

```
g++ -c -Wall $(CodeDefined) $(UserDefined) $(Main) -std=c++0x -lpthread -o main.o
```

CodeDefined and UserDefined are just -U -D options Main is the path to main.cpp file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has nothing to do with compiling and linking.  It is for *runtime* direction of the path to load dynamic libraries.

You should add the following switch (or something similar) to tell `g++` where to find the cuda include files:

```
-I/usr/local/cuda/include
```